# What would be prefered semantic and accessible markup for this iOS contact like divider list?

Tags: css, html, semantic-markup

What would be prefered semantic and accessible markup for this divider list?

[image]

I'm using jQuery mobile for a project and it uses this mark-up

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-dividertheme="d" data-inset="true"> 
    <li data-role="list-divider">A</li> 
    <li><a href="index.html">Adam Kinkaid</a></li> 
    <li><a href="index.html">Alex Wickerham</a></li> 
    <li><a href="index.html">Avery Johnson</a></li> 
    <li data-role="list-divider">B</li> 
    <li><a href="index.html">Bob Cabot</a></li> 
    <li data-role="list-divider">C</li> 
    <li><a href="index.html">Caleb Booth</a></li> 
    <li><a href="index.html">Christopher Adams</a></li> 
</ul>
```

I think for dividers (A,B,C...) HTML Heading tags should be used.

Comment: Is `data-role="list-divider"` listed in any spec? I’m not very familiar with ARIA, but I couldn’t see `list-divider` in the spec anywhere.

Comment: I think we can use anything between `data-*="*"` http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Comment: sure, but as far as end users go, `data-role="list-divider"` is meaningless. Like you say, I think the dividers should be headings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definately not `ul` since it is aplhabetical it should be either `ol` with `list-style-type:upper-alpha;` with nested list.

I would go with a html something like:

```
<ol>
   <li>
      <ul>
         <li>Adam</li>
         <li>Alan</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ol>
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/easwee/8UUbh/5/

Comment: oh i think this is as sexy solution. But i would wrap the Letter in a strong element so you can give it a data-role. (Or format it)

Comment: @meo If he did a `list-style-type:upper-alpha` he wouldn't even need to type the A in since the list would be semantically an ordered list and the bullets would be alphabeticaly "numbered" (excuse poor english) anyway.

Comment: @easwee: would you want to rely on generated content for your list section headings though? (Obviously we’re down at the semantic hair-splitting level anyway, but I’m not sure). Also, can you style the generated alphabetical “numbering”?

Comment: @easwee - Then How we will make multiple dividers with your method. Separate `<ol>` for each? Please give an example with multiple headings.

Comment: @meo: what `data-role` would you apply to the letter headings? [I can’t see `list-divider` in the WAI spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#roles_categorization).

Comment: @Jitendra: oh FFS. `<ol>
   <li>
       A
      <ul>
         <li>Adam</li>
         <li>Alan</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
       B
      <ul>
         <li>Bob</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
<ol>`

Comment: @Jitendra Vyas Added a sample file.

Comment: @Paul, @easwee - Thanks. `data-role="listview"` and `data-role="list-divider"` are necessary to use to make it work with jQuery Mobile.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite - Not sure what data-role to use but something along this: http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#listitem ? What's your opinion on this?

Comment: @easwee - Your code is fine. but sometime I also need to write longer heading rather than just letters then in that condition what you would suggest

Comment: @Jitendra Vyas - I would still use an `<ol>`, but with `list-style:none;` set and I would insert the longer heading. Just think about it logicaly - the elements is still ordered in some alphanumeric structure - you are just deciding whether to display the label or not - same as with input forms imo.

Comment: @easwee - and in your example http://jsfiddle.net/easwee/8UUbh/5/ if we disable css then A > 1 , B > 2

Comment: @Jitendra Vyas - You have a type value for ol `<ol type="A">` http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ol.html#ol.attrs.type .

Comment: @easwee let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1835/discussion-between-jitendra-vyas-and-easwee)

Comment: @easwee: yeah, I don’t think I would apply a data-role to it (aside from whatever this jQuery plugin requires), as (purely from scanning the spec, not actually being familiar with it) I can’t see anything that applies. (`listitem` seems redundant for something in an `<li>` tag already.) As far as I can see, the letters are headings for the sub-lists, so I think I’d wrap a `<section>` around the letter and the sub-list, and mark the letter up with an `<h1>`. I.e. http://jsfiddle.net/GUB4p/

Comment: @Paul D. Waite - Multiple `<h1>`?

Comment: @Jitendra: sure, I’ve added a JSFiddle link to my comment above showing what I mean.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite - yes I saw, removed my comment.

Comment: @Jitendra: yup, in HTML5 you can have as many `<h1>`s as you want, as long as they’re each within a sectioning context or a sectioning root. See http://diveintohtml5.org/semantics.html#article-element

Answer (score 1):

I would use a definition list

```
<dl data-role="listview" data-dividertheme="d" data-inset="true"> 
   <dt data-role="list-divider">A</dt>
   <dd>blblblaba</dd>
</dl>
```

I know that the titles are not definition titles, but its clear what elements are the dividers and what elements are the contents.

**edit** i think @easwee's solution is much better in a semantic point of view.

Comment: But actually these are unordered list

Comment: i don't think it matters when the data-role is set. But i would use @easwee's solution anyway.